# How can I indicate if our donors prefer to receive Charitable/Political Tax Receipts by Email or Postal Mail?

Tags: extension, cdn-tax-receipts

using:
CDN Tax Receipts Extension
https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts

Answer (score 2):

The CDN Tax Receipts extension contains several hooks - one of them allows you to set the 'method' of delivery (Email vs Print) for a specific Contact. Here's an example implementation:

```
/**
 * Determine Contact's Preferred Communication Method
 * return 'print' -> if Postal Mail is checked
 */
function my_receipts_cdntaxreceipts_method($contactId) {

  // Check if Contact's Preferred Communication Method = Postal Mail -> id = 3
  $result_pcm_id = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
    'return' => "preferred_communication_method",
    'id' => $contactId,
  ));

  if ($result_pcm_id['is_error'] != 1) {
    if (count($result_pcm_id['values'][$contactId]['preferred_communication_method']) == 1) {
      if ($result_pcm_id['values'][$contactId]['preferred_communication_method'][0] == 3) {
        return array('print');
      }
    }
  }
}
```